# Delphi: how I can determine the downloading speed in kbps?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, wininet

I use to download the files some functions of wininet:

```
 Url := source_file;

 destinationfilename := destination_file;
 hInet := InternetOpen(PChar(application.title), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,
   nil, nil, 0);
 hFile := InternetOpenURL(hInet, PChar(Url), nil, 0,
   INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE, 0);

 if Assigned(hFile) then
 begin
   AssignFile(localFile, destinationfilename);
   Rewrite(localFile, 1);
   repeat
     InternetReadFile(hFile, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), bytesRead);
     BlockWrite(localFile, Buffer, bytesRead);
     current_size := current_size + bytesRead;
   until (bytesRead = 0) OR (terminated = True);
   CloseFile(localFile);
   InternetCloseHandle(hFile);
 end;
 InternetCloseHandle(hInet);
```

I'm trying to determine the download speed so, but gets some strange values:

```
   ...
   repeat
     QueryPerformanceFrequency(iCounterPerSec);
     QueryPerformanceCounter(T1);

     InternetReadFile(hFile, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), bytesRead);
     BlockWrite(localFile, Buffer, bytesRead);
     current_size := current_size + bytesRead;
     QueryPerformanceCounter(T2);

     _speed := round((bytesRead / 1024) / ((T2 - T1) / iCounterPerSec));

     download_speed := inttostr(_speed) + ' kbps';
   until (bytesRead = 0) OR (terminated = True);
   ...
```

So the question is how I can determine the downloading speed in kbps? Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: The unit should read 'kB/s', not 'kbps'.

Comment: What's wrong with dividing the number of bytes by the time taken to download those bytes?

Comment: I hope buffer is rather big. It should be. If you only read a few bytes at a time, you are doing this in a bad way, and might see strange numbers.

Comment: Another hint: replace `current_size := current_size + bytesRead;` by `Inc(current_size, bytesRead)` and replace `terminated = true` by simply `terminated`. Also, you use two different variable naming conventions! Either use `method_one` or (preferably) `methodTwo`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: yes, I think `bytesRead` is 2048 bytes in each loop.

Comment: @RedOctober: That sounds very reasonable. But if you have a very fast Internet connection (100 Mbit/sec or so), it might still be too little. Do you get better values if you add a zero or two to 2048?

Comment: What does "strange" mean? What value do you get, and what value do you expect to see instead? Your code doesn't actually *do* anything with the calculated value, so how do you observe it to determine that it's strange in the first place?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: yes, just tried to increase the buffer to 8192 bytes, and then to 16384 bytes. Works a little better, but still pretty weird: `_speed` value can be 170, 165, 173, and then suddenly 50 or something like this. Then again: 163, 175, etc. Also, if I run multiple concurrent downloads - it does not affect `_speed` at all.

Comment: @RedOctober: Perhaps the server hosting the file you download is the factor limiting the download speed, and not your Internet connection? The load on the server might also vary with time.

Comment: Does the speed reported by your program seem to agree with the actual time it takes to download the file (given its known size)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Except that the abbreviation *kbps* is for kilobits instead of kilobytes, your code looks fine to me. You have the number of kilobytes transferred, you have the time it took to transfer, and you divide the two values.

The numbers will fluctuate over time. To smooth the numbers out, you might wish to use a [moving average](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MovingAverage.html) instead.

There are various factors that could affect your measurements. For example, there are multiple layers of buffering in effect. If the Delphi file buffer is large, then some calls to `BlockWrite` will simply be copying memory from `Buffer` into the internal buffer maintained for `localFile`, whereas other calls will include flushing the buffer to disk. Likewise, the OS could have file buffers that only get written sometimes. Thus, you're measuring not only your download speed, but also your disk I/O speed. Increasing the size of `Buffer` will lessen the effect because you're more likely to exhaust the file buffers on each iteration. A moving average would counteract variations introduced by accumulating and flushing buffers.

The server, or some router between you and the server, could be limiting the speed, and that could explain why you seem to get the same measurement even when there is other concurrent network traffic.